# How to create table merge with div

Tags: html, laravel

This is my `<div>` for create form.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <x-selects.singlehorizontal id='product_id' label='ProductID' :option='App\Product::pluck("code","id")' placeholder='null'/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <x-inputs.texts.horizontal id='Lot' type='text' label='Lot No'/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <x-selects.singlehorizontal id='endproduct_id' label='End Product Name' :option='App\Product::pluck("code","id")' placeholder='null'/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <x-inputs.datehorizontal id='pro_date' label='ProDate'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

that will show like this

```
[Question] : [Input]   [Question] : [Input]  +----------+
[Question] : [Input]   [Question] : [Input]  |[Question]|
[Question] : [Input]   [Question] : [Input]  |----------|<- I I want to make a box with 5 lines
[Question] : [Input]   [Question] : [Input]  |          |
[Question] : [Input]   [Question] : [Input]  |  [Input] |
[Question] : [Input]   [Question] : [Input]  +----------+
```

and on the right, ... is that possible with `<div>` and how to fit input field with the box height?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="until.css">
</head>

<body>



        <table>
            <tr ><td>Question</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="question"></td> <td>question</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="question"></td> </tr>
            <tr ><td>Question</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="question"></td> <td>question</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="question"></td> </tr> 

        <tr ><td>Question</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="question"></td> <td>question</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="question"></td> </tr> 


            <tr ><td>Question</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="question"></td> <td>question</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="question"></td> </tr> 


            <tr ><td>Question</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="question"></td> <td>question</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="question"></td> </tr> 


            <tr ><td>Question</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="question"></td> <td>question</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="question"></td><td ><button id="large">sumbit</button></td>  </tr> 




        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
#large{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
     position: absolute;
  left: 38%;
  top: 5%;
   text-align: center;
  font-size: 23px;
}
```

this should work

Comment: thank's, but i want to add big box on right table with div.. is it possible?

Comment: yes it is with some css, you just want the submit button bigger or what ?

Comment: i added the css to make the box bigger im not sure if that what you looking for tho

Comment: please tell me if  the answer that i just edited fits your need ?

Comment: I want to make a box in cell with merge 5 row on last column.. and fit input field in it..

Comment: if you can show me an example how you want it maybe a link to a website that got the same thing or draw it to me i can help you better. but im sorry i cant understand what you mean exactly